# i am trying to load my view from the controller in spring, net beans, with Glass fish server 4.0: following are the respective classes

Tags: java, spring

**MY ControllerClass:**
I am trying to bind this controller class with its respective view called `priceincrease.jsp`

I am new to spring and i found out that this `SimpleFormController` class has been depricated since spring 3.0. How do i use controller to bind with my view? 
Could anyone help me ?

```
public class PriceIncreaseController extends SimpleFormController { 
    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 
    private ProductManager productManager; 
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)
            throws ServletException { 
        int increase = ((PriceIncrease) command).getPercentage();
        logger.info("Increasing prices by " + increase + "%."); 
        productManager.increasePrice(increase); 
        logger.info("returning from PriceIncreaseForm view to " + getSuccessView()); 
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
    } 
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
        priceIncrease.setPercentage(20);
        return priceIncrease;
    } 
    public void setProductManager(ProductManager productManager) {
        this.productManager = productManager;
    } 
    public ProductManager getProductManager() {
        return productManager;
    } 
}
```

**My priceincrease.jsp:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title><fmt:message key="title"/></title>
  <style>
    .error { color: red; }
  </style>  
</head>
<body>
<h1><fmt:message key="priceincrease.heading"/></h1>
<form:form method="post" commandName="priceIncrease">
  <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20%">Increase (%):</td>
        <td width="20%">
          <form:input path="percentage"/>
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
          <form:errors path="percentage" cssClass="error"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" align="center" value="Execute">
</form:form>
<a href="<c:url value="inventory.htm"/>">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**My dispatcher-servelet.xml**

```
<bean name="/priceincrease.htm" class="web.PriceIncreaseController">
        <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
        <property name="commandName" value="priceIncrease"/>
        <property name="commandClass" value="service.PriceIncrease"/>

        <property name="validator">
            <bean class="service.PriceIncreaseValidator"/>
        </property>
        <property name="formView" value="priceincrease"/>
        <property name="successView" value="inventory.htm"/>
        <property name="productManager" ref="productManager"/>
    </bean>
```

**This is the error i have received:**

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils note The full
>   stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the
>   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with Spring you can mark your controllers with @Controller annotations.

For eg.

```
    @Controller
    public class DispensaryController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String dispensary(Model model) {
         // This can be used in the jsp as ${name} when you access it.
         model.addAttribute("name", "Santosh");
         return "testPage";
       }
    }
```

Also include this in your servlet if you want to return pages

```
 <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```